# Trouble with Copying VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on an independent project for a client of mine. They wanted to produce a button that, upon the user-click, it would open up a user-form and have a variety of macro-related options to choose from: a drop-down list, checkbox, option select button, etc.

I created a test formula and submitted it to the client; they enjoyed it thoroughly and decided to sent me a file to 'copy & paste' my original code within their excel file.

Problem is; because I'm a tad bit inexperienced with VBA I've run into a problem where once I click the button - the user form doesn't show up.

Below is a Dropbox link of the original file I created and it's original code; as well as the file that I am trying to copy.

Any help would be all welcome and appreciated.

Link to dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l1t37lz8uritrua/AAAdWPGvw0GDZ6hW4SwmbBdRa?dl=0

Comment: When I attempt to save your files from Dropbox, it wants to save them as Htm files.  I cannot access your code. If I understand correctly, you have copied the code to the client's workbook.  Have you also copied the form?

Comment: If you hit the download button it will give you the option to open the files in excel. And the code I copied I did my best to match the characteristics of the code that was in the original file (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Thanks for the instructions, I had not notices the Download button. I have now successfully downloaded your files. I will examine them. This is your question so you automatically get a message in your Inbox when a comment it posted again it. If you start your reply with an @ immediately followed by my name, I will get a message saying you have replied.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I apologize, I did not know that; thank you for the clarifications! As well as your help.

Comment: No need to apologise. Omitting my name just means you have to wait until I go through my recent comments to see if there are any replies.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thank you, I will follow as you stated; I'm not sure why I am getting that error as well.

Answer (score 0):

OriginalProject.xlsm has a form named **honor_roll_form** which contains 100 lines of code.

CopyOfOriginal.xlsm  has a form named **UserForm1** which contains no useful code.

I do not believe there is any method of directly copying user forms from one workbook to another.  Instead

- Within VB Editor of OriginalProject.xlsm, select honor_roll_form.
- Click File then Export File and save the form on your desktop or where ever you like.
- You will now have two files on your desktop; one with an extension of frm and one with an extension of frx.
- Within VB Editor of CopyOfOriginal.xlsm, click File then Import file.
- Import honor_roll_form.frm

When I try clicking button "Honor Roll", I get "Method or data member not found" for project1Box. I will investigate after dinner (18:57 here) unless you tell me you already know why I am getting this error.

**Extra comments in response to request from OP**

It is late here but I have started looking down sub execute_button_Click within the second CopyOfOriginal.xlsm.  I will comment on what I see even if it is not directly relevant to the non-execution of the macro.

If you open the VB Editor and look on the left you will see the Project Explorer.  Near the top you will see:

```
Microsoft Excel Objects
    Sheet1 (Sheet1)
```

I have always found this confusing. The first “Sheet1” is Excel’s Id for the worksheet and cannot be changed.  The second “Sheet1” is the default name for the worksheet which can be changed.  You can write `Sheet1.Range("A1")` or `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`.  That is: you can reference a worksheet by its Id or its name.  You have named a variable of type Worksheet as Sheet1. Using Excel’s names as variable names can lead to bizarre errors so it is important to avoid doing anything like this.

It is better to always use meaningful names.  At the moment, you know what Sheet1 means but if you come back to this macro in six or twelve months will you remember.  I would use a variable as you have but I would name it WshtCis208 or WshtVBAProg or something similar.

`Set ID = Range(Sheet1.Cells(2, 1), Sheet1.Cells(52, 1))` could be written as:

```
With WshtCis208
  Set ID = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(52, 1))
End With
```

Using `With statements` produces faster code and, almost always, code that it easier to read.

“52” is the current bottom row for this table. Will you amend the macro for them every time they add or remove a student?  There are several techniques for finding the last row, none of which is perfect in every situation. The technique that is the most convenient most of the time is:

```
Const ColCis208Id as Long = 1
Const ColCis208MidTermExam as Long = 5

Dim RowCis208Last as Long

RowCis208Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColCis208Id).End(xlUp).Row
```

At the moment, column 1 is the Id column.  It is perhaps unlikely that the Id column will move but it is very likely that some of the others columns will move when some new column is identified as useful.  Do you want to scan the code trying to decide which 5s refer to the MidtermExam column when a Project3 column is added?

Constants allow you to name literals that might change. It makes your code easier to read and saves so much pain when a value changes.

`.Rows.Count` gives the number of rows in a worksheet for the current version of Excel so `.Cells(.Rows.Count, ColCis208Id)` identifies the bottom cell of column 1.  `End(xlUp).Row` says go up until you hit a cell with a value and returns its row number. It is the VBA equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.

The next statement `subjectCount = …` fails because projectBox does not exist on the form. You have changed the captions but not the names.

As far as I can see the form fails to execute because you have started updating it but have not finished.

Comment: I did exactly as stated and copied and paste the initial code from my workbook into the user form and I now receive the message you stated in your answer. I went into the userform and edited the text of the check-boxes but that still did not work.

Comment: @JerryStackhouse. The versions of sub `honor_roll_button` in OriginalProject and CopyOfOriginal are not the same.  The statements under "'Setting default check boxes" are different. In CopyOfOriginal they address buttons that do not exist. Perhaps you need to copy module show_button across as well.

Comment: I did just as you stated and now I am getting a debug error about line Me.Projectbox1.Value - I can't @ you.

Comment: @JerryStackhouse You do not have to @ me because this is my answer. I have to @ you. The code attempts to access Project1Box but there is no such control on the form. If you want the same form on both workbooks, why not the same code?

Comment: Here is the link with the update copyproject: | https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fo8q58alegzgkz/CopyofOriginal.xlsm?dl=0 | I mean, wouldn't the code not work because the code within the form button is different? That's why I changed it so that it would match the criteria I was looking for. Idk, in all honesty, I'm just confusing myself - but hopefully once you see the updated file maybe you'll understand.

Comment: @JerryStackhouse I have loaded the new workbook and the form now loads.  Is there another problem? The original question was about the form not loading. I have not looked further.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Here is a very easy way to copy a form over: drag & drop! Open both files and then drag & drop the form from one file into the other file (within the VBE). Done.

Comment: @Ralph.  Thanks for the information. I have not tried for many years; drag and drop must be a "newish" enhancement because I remember when it did not work,

Comment: Yeah, the form opens you anwsered my question regarding that. Unfortunately it doesnt run the macro. Im away from my computer at the moment but I guess I have to submit a new question now. However if you could help resolve this issue of mine I'd appreciate it

Comment: @Ralph.  Please do not edit my answer.  You should create your own answer.  I have not deleted your text so you can copy it to your own answer. Once you have, please delete your text from my answer.  This is useful material and is well explained but incorrectly placed.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I didn't edit any text in your answer. I merely added a screen-cast in form of a `GIF` to illustrate how you can easily move a form from one file to another (in response to your third line of your answer). Upon your request I removed the `GIF` (only).

Comment: @Ralph  I realised when I edited my answer that there was no text but by then the edit time on my comment had expired.  I suggest you add the GIF to the Excel VBA documentation.  I sure there will be others like me who tried drag and drop years ago, found it did not work for a form and have never tried again.  It is a nice animation and it would be a shame to waste it.